# How to setup kafka over kubernetes with multiple replicas

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka

I am trying to run kafka over kubernetes and when I am trying to increase the replicas then kafka is not working. Sometimes it show broker with similar IDs and sometimes it shows can't resolve the address which I am providing in the advertised_listeners.

I am trying to do manual deployment, any example of deployment yaml will help.

Comment: Start here https://strimzi.io

Comment: @OneCricketeer can't we do it without any operators?

Comment: You can, but you'll need to edit your question to include what you're using. Manual deployments? Helm Charts?

Comment: @OneCricketeer I have edited my question, I am doing manual deployment.

Comment: Okay, so edit your question with your own YAML files since I still think using open source operators or Helm Charts is a far better solution

Comment: Ok I will try that, as of now it is working, I was making mistake in advertise_listeners.

Comment: Btw - https://strimzi.io/docs/operators/latest/deploying.html#setup-external-clients-str